# Spark Query by tblproperties

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible in Spark, to query by table properties?

[Databricks has a page](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-tblproperties.html#tblproperties) where they show an example of using the deparments as "tblproperties".

```
> CREATE TABLE T(c1 INT) TBLPROPERTIES('this.is.my.key' = 12, this.is.my.key2 = true);
> SHOW TBLPROPERTIES T;
option.serialization.format     1
this.is.my.key  12
this.is.my.key2 true
```

I would now like to be able to do somehow get a list of all table names where "this.is.my.key" = 12. Is this possible with e.g. Spark-SQL?

My current solution is to simply loop over  all tables and do the check, but I feel like there could be a "nicer" solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in an "elegant" way.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped to receive, but it makes sense as nothing in this direction is documented. Thanks!

Comment: Some people do not like no for answer. Not you though. Success.